# Get event target after frame loads - Turbo Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I have some turbo frame forms in my page that should fire some javascript after they are loaded into the document. Therefore I'm using the `turbo:frame-load` event listener. To access the `<turbo-frame>` element I'd like to use the event's target, as mentioned in the documentation (https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events):

> turbo:frame-load fires when  element is navigated and finishes loading (fires after turbo:frame-render). The specific  element is the event target.

Here my code:

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener('turbo:frame-load', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

However this returns not the `<turbo-frame>` element, but the `<html>` element instead. Does anyone know how to get the `<turbo-frame>` instead?